Use windows 11 to forward traffic between 2 LANs
I have Windows 11 with IP addresses 192.168.72.100, 192.168.10.113, connected to two LANs:
192.168.10.1/24
192.168.72.1/24
From a host on 192.168.10.1/24, I would like to ping, and http/vnc to machine on 192.168.72.1/24.
I set HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter to 1, and restarted Windows. I enabled RemoteAccess with:
sc config RemoteAccess start=auto
sc start RemoteAccess

But from host on 192.168.10.1/24, I cannot ping hosts on 192.168.72.1/24, except the Windows machine itself:
ping 192.168.72.101
PING 192.168.72.101 (192.168.72.101): 56 data bytes
(hangs forever)

I can ping Windows machine just fine:
ping 192.168.72.100
PING 192.168.72.100 (192.168.72.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.72.100: seq=0 ttl=127 time=0.638 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.72.100: seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.591 ms

I turned off Windows Defender Firewall.
What else I need to do to enable pinging (and http/vnc) in this situation?

What routes / what default gateway do machines in 192.168.10.0/24 currently use?

They are using gateway 192.168.10.1

Does that gateway have a route to 192.168.72.0/24 configured? Or, do the computers themselves have a route to 192.168.72.0/24 configured?

Yes, there is a static route. This is how I can ping the Windows machine on the IP 192.168.72.100 from a device on the network

My static route: https://imgur.com/iVeVIgN

How about the other side – does the 192.168.72.x network's gateway have a route back to the 192.168.10.0/24 network?

I don't think there is. The network 192.168.72.x is using some protocol I don't know but there are no gateway defined on the subnet. But from the windows machine (192.168.72.100) I can ping to other devices (like 192.168.72.101) and the ping works just fine. It just won't work if I attempt to ping from a device outside that subnet.

Well yes, because in the first case you're pinging from an IP address that's in the same subnet (so the devices know how to reply), and in the second case you're pinging from an IP address in a different subnet (so the devices have no idea which MAC to send a reply to). Does that subnet have no gateway at all?

Yes, the subnet have no gateway. But I wonder if these devices know how to send a reply to the Windows machine, shouldn't the windows machine know enough to send the packets back to the pinger?

If I replace Windows machine by an OpenWRT router, the pinging works. So I would like to think this is just specific to Windows machine, it needs to be configured for packet forwarding to work like a router.

@PhuongNguyen You need a route. Enable packet forwarding makes your machine a router. If a device doesn't have a valdi route, it can't send packets to other subnets.


As I said, literally because of the IP addresses (and netmask). The 192.168.72.101 device is configured with a /24 netmask, so it recognizes the 192.168.72.100 Windows machine as a "local subnet" address and will directly ARP query for its MAC address. But likewise, the same device knows that 192.168.10.x is not "local" and therefore won't attempt to ARP query it (as that wouldn't work anyway), it knows it needs to use a gateway – and you said there's no gateway configured, neither default or otherwise.



Your OpenWRT router probably has NAT (masquerading) enabled, where it literally rewrites the source IP address with its own – the devices think they're replying to the OpenWRT router (which is "local" to them) instead of the original sender. That's the default setting for "LAN → WAN" traffic on home wireless routers. Windows RRAS doesn't NAT anything by default, it preserves the original address like a "pure" router would. So if you found a way to enable NAT, that'd work around your "no gateway" problem.


If I replace Windows machine by an OpenWRT router, the pinging works. So I would like to think this is just specific to Windows machine  The OpenWRT router may implement proxy arp, which may enable the router to handle this scenario better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP

Although your 192.168.10.0/24 network has a valid route to the 192.168.72.0/24 network, you're missing the return route from 192.168.72.0/24 to 192.168.10.0/24.
"Reply" packets do not automatically know their return route; each packet is routed independently without making any distinction between initial packet or reply packet. In other words, when devices receive an IP packet, they don't remember which MAC address it came from and won't simply send replies the same way¹ but perform a brand new route lookup and a new ARP query.
¹ (Aside from Mikrotik's weird "SwOS" switch firmware, which does exactly that.)
As a result:

Your 192.168.72.x device is configured with a /24 netmask, so it recognizes the 192.168.72.y Windows PC as a "local subnet" address (for which it automatically has a direct route) and is able to reply to the pings by directly querying ARP for the PC's MAC address.

At the same time, when pinged by 192.168.10.x, the device correctly recognizes 192.168.10.x as non-local and knows that the reply packets must be delivered through a gateway's MAC address instead. But since the device has no default gateway (nor a static route) configured, there's no way for it to send the reply packet.


So the 192.168.72.x devices would need to have either a specific route to 192.168.10.0/24 via the Windows router, or a default route, either way somehow telling them where to deliver the packets.
As a workaround, the intermediate router can do SNAT (aka masquerading), where it replaces the original sender's IP address with its own address – which will of course be "local" to the device. For example, OpenWRT has SNAT enabled by default for all "LAN→WAN" traffic (as is generally expected from a home wireless router), so everything seems to work when you're using the OpenWRT router in the middle – as long as the SNAT is enabled in the correct direction.
It seems that Windows 10/11 supports NAT natively and you can enable it using Add-NetNat in PowerShell (it's what it uses for Hyper-V WSL2, so I'm not 100% sure whether it works without Hyper-V installed). Specify 192.168.72.0/24 as the "External" prefix.
(Similarly, the "Internet Connection Sharing" feature always does NAT, though it also imposes some other hard-coded configuration and is probably too inflexible for your setup.)
Previously there also used to be a NAT implementation as part of RRAS (at least in Server 2003), but I suspect it may have been removed in favor of the new one.
But it would probably be best to continue using an OpenWRT device as the router, or at least boot Linux or *BSD on the PC – even though Windows can route, it's far from ideal for that purpose.


There is no NetNat supports on my Windows 11 Pro(ARM):
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetNat => Get-NetNat : Invalid class;
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object WindowsVersion, WindowsEditionId => 2009           Professional

Try installing Hyper-V via "Features". Wouldn't be the first time a seemingly unrelated function turned out to be part of the Hyper-V module. Otherwise, use a different OS.
